# specs for professional-grade local machine

Tags: machine-learning, python

What are the expected specs for the local machine that a mid-tier data science professional would expect to find on their desk at work? I'm looking for very solid, but nothing extraordinary.

To say a little more: if I were a professional data scientist training NLP and image recognition models locally over decently large (but still locally containable) datasets using Python, what are the minimum specs my machine would have these days? The last time I was doing anything like this, it was a 16GB minimum. Is it now 32, or 64? How many cores? Etc.

Comment: If there's a better forum to ask this question, please let me know here and I'll delete.

Comment: I don't know what forum this would be best for, but to answer your question: training pretty much exclusively occurs on GPUs now. For a local machine, it would be pretty standard to have a couple nice GPUs (e.g. 1080ti). The model and dataset dictate the memory requirements, but minibatch training and full x16 lane pcie port often work around very large dataset limitations. The cpu is less relevant because it just needs to keep up with the kernel launches and memcpy's. Also, I don't know how multithreaded the standard libraries are, but again, the cpu is less relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the professional has to deal with large datasets and/or computer-intensive tasks (not always the case), the local machine doesn't matter: what matters is access to some kind of high-performance cluster or cloud computing.

Comment: Thank you very much